# GRANT or REVOKE queries executed directly from the Cassandra code require Authorization

Tags: cassandra

i have been studying Cassandra recently. I have seen that some queries are made when starting Cassandra, for example the creation of a default superuser in CassandraRoleManager.java.

```
private static void setupDefaultRole()
    {
        if (StorageService.instance.getTokenMetadata().sortedTokens().isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException("CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: no known tokens in ring");

        try
        {
            if (!hasExistingRoles())
            {
                QueryProcessor.process(createDefaultRoleQuery(),
                                       consistencyForRoleWrite(DEFAULT_SUPERUSER_NAME));
                logger.info("Created default superuser role '{}'", DEFAULT_SUPERUSER_NAME);
            }
        }
        catch (RequestExecutionException e)
        {
            logger.warn("CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static String createDefaultRoleQuery()
    {
        return String.format("INSERT INTO %s.%s (role, is_superuser, can_login, salted_hash) VALUES ('%s', true, true, '%s') USING TIMESTAMP 0",
                             SchemaConstants.AUTH_KEYSPACE_NAME,
                             AuthKeyspace.ROLES,
                             DEFAULT_SUPERUSER_NAME,
                             escape(hashpw(DEFAULT_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD)));
    }
```

It appears that all queries such as CREATE, INSERT, SELECT, ..., can be used with ClientState isInternal set to TRUE and are executed without any authentication or authorization checks.

```
    /**
     * Construct a new, empty ClientState for internal calls.
     */
    private ClientState()
    {
        this.isInternal = true;
        this.remoteAddress = null;
    }
```

For GRANT or REVOKE operations it's not the same. I tried running a GRANT to the default superuser and got a NullPointerException. The difference seems to be the existence of the PermissionsManagementStatement.java, which does not check the isInternal state in the ClientState.

TEST query: "GRANT CREATE ON KEYSPACE system TO cassandra" Fail with NullPointerException on ClientState.authorize(resource), because AuthenticatedUser is not set in the ClientState when isInternal is TRUE during setup flow.

TEST query: "INSERT INTO system_auth.role_permissions (role, resource, permissions) values ('cassandra', 'data/system', {'CREATE'})" run succesfully.

Is this intended behaviour? If so, why?